# plot survival curve after adjusting for gender

Tags: r, survival-analysis, covariant

I have a dataset that have samples with / without treatment and their ages at death and gender. All the samples are dead. I want to test if the treatment affects the survival.

The dataset df looks like below

```
  FID gender age_at_death treatment event
1 101 female      46  Y     1
2 102 female      65  Y     1
3 103   male      73  Y     1
4 104   male      74  N     1
5 105 female      56  N     1
6 106   male      57  N     1
```

Below is my code to test if the treatment affects survival:

```
library(survminer)    
surv_obj <- Surv(time=df$age_at_death, event=df$event)
fit <- survfit(surv_obj ~treatment, data=df)
ggsurvplot(fit, data = df, pval = TRUE, title = "test" )
```

## surv plot for different treatment group

[image]

But gender is quite an important co variant (females usually live longer than males), therefore I want to adjust for gender. But the below code give me 4 survival curves. What I want is two curves (treated vs non-treat) adjusted for gender.

```
fit1 <- survfit(surv_obj ~treatment + gender, data=df)
ggsurvplot(fit, data = df, pval = TRUE, title = "test" )
```

[image]

```
fit2 <- coxph( Surv(time=df$age_at_death, event=df$event) ~ treatment, data = df )
ggadjustedcurves(fit2, data = df)
```

This only give one curve.

[image]

```
fit3 <- coxph( Surv(time=df$age_at_death, event=df$event) ~ treatment +strata(gender), data = df )
ggadjustedcurves(fit3, data = df)
```

This gives twos curve, male vs female.

[image]

The figure I want is similar to this example:

[image]

"after adjustment for age, sex, race, diseases suspected to influence B27 testing and mortality". They adjusted for quite a few covariants and have an adjusted survival plot for B27+ and B27- (mine is treated vs non-treated).

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: How do you want to adjust? (i.e. what kind and how much of an effect do you attribute to gender?) If this is unclear, try showing the data for your whole sample including male and female, or separately and differantiate the effects.

Comment: I want to show the treatment effect on mortality by adjusting the gender affect. I can do it by cox model but I can't produce a survival plot  showing just treat vs non-treat with adjustment of gender.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at the `adjustedCurves` package: https://github.com/RobinDenz1/adjustedCurves

It offers a variety of ways to adjust survival curves for confounders. The literature references given in the documentation of that package can also be used to get a good understanding of what exactly confounder-adjustment means in this context and how it is performed.